# Add PHP to Expression Web?

Tags: php, microsoft-expression-web

How do you add PHP to Microsoft Expression Web? I have looked for a solution but nothing has worked so far. I have tried downloading from PHP.net but that is not working, also, I added XAMMP to my computer but I don't know how to add it to expression, if that's even possible.

Comment: Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/ee662148.aspx.  If it doesn't work, please give more information regarding 1) what versions you're using, and 2) what specific errors you're getting.

Comment: Microsoft Expression Web is just an editor right?

Comment: You shouldn't need XAMPP. Expression Web already has, I believe, a web server. [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webplatform/archive/2009/10/21/php-support-with-expression-web-3.aspx). In fact, if you install XAMPP it will probably fight with IIS over possession of port 80.

Comment: I tried your idea twice paul, neither times did I have the PHP section in the bottom of the general tab in application settings. Andy, I now removed XAMPP.

Comment: Also how do you find out your current version?